# userdel command produces "DIRECTORY_PATH not owned by USER, not removing" error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I've started learning Linux commands and I was doing simple things like adding new users and groups and deleting them. When I try to delete a user which I created using the syntax "userdel username", it gets deleted with no issues at all but when I try to do the same using userdel -r username it produces the error I've specified in the title.

Note: I'm doing all these things when I'm logged in as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the user's home is not owned by `username` but by another one.

Check which one is it with `grep username /etc/passwd` (penultimate field) and see the permissions it has.

For example:

```
$ grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
                ^^^^^
```

and then

```
$ ls -ld /root
drwx------ 12 root root 4096 Oct 18 12:55 /root
```

Answer (score 2):

The home directory's ownership has changed.  Before using userdel -r, try changing it's ownership back:

```
# chown -R username ~username
```

chown stands for change ownership. -R tells it to recurse into directories.  username is the username of the account you wish to change ownership to, and ~username just means the home directory of the specified user.  This command changes the ownership of the home directory and everything in it back to the user.  Alternatively, you can remove the home directory manually without having to change the ownership of anything:

```
# rm -Rf ~username
# userdel username
```

If prepending the username with a tilde doesn't refer to the home directory of the user, you could use the /etc/passwd file as fidorqui suggested.

```
$ grep username /etc/passwd
```

(grep = search a file or i/o stream)

Each line in /etc/passwd follows this format:
username:password:userid:groupid:comment (UID Info):homedirectory:login shell